Why multer.diskStorage() is not called?
Newcomer to nodejs.
I write the code below and use thunder client to test, finding an error: 500.
Image storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './upload/images',
  filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
    return cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
  }
})
const upload = multer({storage: storage})
// Create upload endpoint for images
app.use('/images', express.static('upload/images'))
app.post("/upload", upload.single('product'), (req, res)=>{
  res.json({
      success: 1,
      image_url: `http://localhost:${port}/images/${req.file.filename}`
  })
})

This is the error information.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')
    at /home/pp/Desktop/E-Commerce/backend/index.js:37:62
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pp/Desktop/E-Commerce/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/pp/Desktop/E-Commerce/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:149:13)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/pp/Desktop/E-Commerce/backend/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:53:37)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)

If I remove image_url, the test can be passed. I am sure other part of the code is correct, because if I remove the code above, everything goes fine.
But actually I am wondering if multer is actually working, because when I add an output in multer.diskStorage() and execute the code below, there is no "hello" on the console. So I think multer.diskStorage() function is not called at all.
Image storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './upload/images',
  filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
    console.log("hello")
    return cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
  }
})
const upload = multer({storage: storage})
// Create upload endpoint for images
app.use('/images', express.static('upload/images'))
app.post("/upload", upload.single('product'), (req, res)=>{
  res.json({
      success: 1,
  })
})

Anyone met such problem before? Thanks a lot!

The fact that req.file is undefined also suggests that multer middleware is not called or something goes wrong there.

the error stack says the multer middleware is called, but the file wasn't found in your request, i.e., it's undefined, hence the error, which all suggests that your request doesn't send file properly. try testing with curl or other agent, or show how you're making the request (add file missing handler, which means the request didn't provide file, for example, if(!req.file) return res.status(400).json({message: 'no file provided'});)

Thanks for reply, I test the code above and indeed get the output 'no file provided'. But I still don't know why this happens. In the testing environment (thunder client), I actually upload an picture.

it didn't detect the file.. try uploading the file with curl or browser or some other tool
